# Flutter BLoC state managment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I decided to study the architecture of BloC. And something really worries me. I was making a login page and noticed that after calling the Emit () function, the TextField () became empty. If I understand correctly, BlocBuilder has rebuilt the entire widget. Is there a way to rebuild only the part that has changed with a single BlocBuilder? Or something smaller.

**UI**:

P.S:
there is a function generate Form () It returns

```js
Column (
  children: [
    TextField (),
    TextField (),
  ],
);
```

```js
    class MainAuth extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CustomScaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is AuthMain) {
                  return mayBe(
                    regForm: generateForm(context.read<AuthBloc>().loginForm,
                        authType.login, context),
                    loginForm: generateForm(context.read<AuthBloc>().regForm,
                        authType.register, context),
                    login: state.type == authType.login,
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class mayBe extends StatelessWidget {
      final Widget regForm;
      final Widget loginForm;
      final bool login;
      mayBe({required this.regForm, required this.loginForm, required this.login});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListenableProvider(
          create: (c) {},
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          ChangedAnimationBlock(
                            index: login ? 0 : 1,
                            children: [
                              Builder(builder: (c) => loginForm),
                              regForm,
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Auth Cubit**:

```js
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:proj/brain/base_functions/forms_to_form.dart';
import 'package:proj/data/repositories/main_api_repository.dart';

part 'auth_state.dart';

class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final MainApiRepository mainApiRepository;
  authType curType = authType.register;
  Map responseRegBody = {};
  Map responseLoginBody = {};

  AuthCubit({required this.mainApiRepository}) : super(AuthInitial()) {
    start();
  }

  Future<void> start() async {
    await getForms();
    emit(
      AuthMain(),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getForms() async {
    await getLoginForm();
    await getRegisterForm();
  }

  void changeType() {
    var currentState = state;
    if (currentState is AuthMain) {
      authType oldAuthType = curType;
      authType newAuthType;
      if (oldAuthType == authType.login) {
        newAuthType = authType.register;
      } else {
        newAuthType = authType.login;
      }
      // curType = newAuthType;

      emit(
        AuthMain(type: newAuthType),
      );
    }
  }

  Map loginForm = {};
  Map regForm = {};

  Future<void> getLoginForm() async {
    var response = await mainApiRepository.getAuthFromSettings();
    loginForm = searchFormIntoForms(response);
    print(response);
    print(loginForm);
    print("loginForm");
  }

  Future<void> getRegisterForm() async {
    var response = await mainApiRepository.getRegistrationFormSettings();
    regForm = searchFormIntoForms(response);
  }
}
```

**Auth state**:

```js
part of 'auth_cubit.dart';

enum authType {
  register,
  login,
}

@immutable
abstract class AuthState {}

class AuthInitial extends AuthState {}

class AuthMain extends AuthState {
  final authType type;
  AuthMain({
    this.type = authType.register,
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you add some example code and show what you have tried?

Comment: @krjw info updated